# In TFS build, can the working directory be on a different partition to the $(SystemDrive)

Tags: tfsbuild

Is it possible to set up a TFS2010 build rule/template to create the build workspace on a different partition to the $(SystemDrive)?

Right now, we have set up a dedicated build server with all tools etc installed to the c:\ partition.  We have created a D:\ partition for all data.

Ideally, I would like all builds to be built in D:\Builds\$(BuildAgentId)\$(BuildDefinitionPath) but still reference all MS links, dependencies etc from the C:\ drive.

I am unsure how this is done

I have tried changing the agent workspace to D:\Builds, but the build then looks for the tools on the D:\ drive.

I have also tried changing the Build Agent Folder in the template to D:\Builds with the same outcome.

I must be missing something as I suspect it should be ok to do this?

Any help/advice/guidance would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Open Visual Studio TeamExplorer and go to Builds in any TeamProject. Rightclick on it and than `Manage Build Controllers...`, select the `Build Agent` you are using and press `Properties..`. Here you can set the `Working Directory` to `d:\Builds\$(BuildAgentId)\$(BuildDefinitionPath)`. This worked fine in all companies I worked for.

What kind of tools is the build looking for? Maybe there is a relative path used, which would not work in another location than the actual one.

Comment: Thanks for your reply Mike, it appears that some environment variables were missing causing the build to fail and somehow log that it was looking for them in the D:\ drive??

Comment: once the environment was sorted, it all worked as expected.  Thanks again :)